# ISAPI Extension TerminateExtension thread deadlock

Tags: multithreading, delphi, isapi

I needed to create statefull ISAPI extension for my project. I successfully made a TSession object that is contained in a TSessionList = class(TObject). For cleanup of expired sessions I made a cleanup thread (TThread descendant) that periodically scans TSessionList and frees all expired sessions.

I create the TSessionList and the CleanupThread in the dpr main execution block. Which is just fine. But actually I am not sure, where to put the destruction of CleanupThread. From documentation I found that ISAPI extension has to export TerminateExtension, which gets called just before the extension is unloaded. Default Delphi ISAPI extension of course exports such a function. So I've "overriden it" = exported my TerminateExtension that frees my session objects and then call default ISAPIAPP.TerminateExtensionProc.

Here it is how it looks like:

```
function TerminateExtension(dwFlags: DWORD): BOOL; stdcall; 
begin
  DoneSessions;
  Result:= ISAPIApp.TerminateExtension(dwFlags);
end;

exports   
  GetExtensionVersion,   
  HttpExtensionProc,
  TerminateExtension;

begin   
  CoInitFlags := COINIT_MULTITHREADED;
  Application.Initialize;
  InitSessions;
  Application.CreateForm(TSOAPWebModule, SOAPWebModule);
  Application.Run;
end.
```

The CleanupThread destruction is done in DoneSessions this way:

```
begin
  CleanupThread.Free;
  SessionList.Free;
end;
```

The CleanupThread is simple descendant of TThread, so do not look for anything specific in its destruction code.

The problem is that the TerminateExtension freezes just in CleanupThread.Free. Debugging further I did find that freeze happens in the TThread.WaitFor. I suspect there must be some kind of thread deadlock = ISAPI worker thread is waiting for my extension to terminate, which waits in TThread.WaitFor for the main thread to get signaled (or whatever).

I know I could overcome this situation calling CleanupThread.Terminate, then using direct WaitForSingleObject (or Multiple???) and finally freeing it. But that sounds a bit ... nonstandard.

Therefore my question is: How and when should i Free (Terminate - WaitFor - Destroy) any support threads in ISAPI extension to avoid thread deadlock?

BTW: I already found the same in standard DLL. If you put any thread.WaitFor in the dll unload proc, your main app freezes just in library unload. So the same question/answer hopefully applies here.

Answer (score 0):

You should try signalling the thread terminate before calling free, for example;

```
CleanupThread.Terminate;
if CleanupThread.Waitfor(60000)<>WR_Abandoned then //wait for 60sec for cleanup
  CleanupThread.free
else
  //do something sensible on timeout or error
```

But without knowing what, exactly, the cleanup thread is trying to do it is hard to say what could be causing a deadlock.  Often these are the result of race conditions, especially if a terminate & waitfor times out, so you need to specify what the thread is doing.

As a hack (and not good practice for multithreading) you can force a thread to exit using the winapi call TERMINATETHREAD (in the Windows unit);

```
TerminateThread(CleanupThread.handle,0);
```

As this forces an immediate exit on the thread but also means no thread cleanup is performed - remember that calling TTHREAD.TERMINATE does not guarantee that a thread will exit - this is entirely dependant on your thread code, if something is blocking your thread then it will not terminate in the normal manner.  TerminateThread can solve this, at the expense of the code simply stopping where it is with no regard for any resource freeing or what other threads are up to.